# Omega 16 Columns

Tags: 7, theming

By default, Omega is loading the 12 column grid (alpha-default-normal-12.css).  How do I have it load the 16 column grid (alpha-default-normal-16.css)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goto the settings page for your theme, eg "admin/appearance/settings/mytheme".

Make sure you have the 960gs selected, and choose your default width (narrow, normal, wide, or fluid).

Open the "Zone and region configuration tab".  Bang down into a zone, then the configuration for the zone.  Choose your column count (12, 16, or 24).  You need to do this for each zone; each zone can have a different column count.

Save your configuration.